# Observable.expand and use an array to make a single observable based request using mergeMap?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a query which can be multiple requests and each of them is an observable and is using an .expand to recursively look thru each observable and make a request.

When the object's Count is > 1 we go ahead and do a post request and create an obj and if the count is 0 we delete the obj that just got created. This part of the code already exists

I need help to make it such that instead of deleting each object by its Id , I want to push all the id's to an array and later send a bulk delete request with the array of id's as the payload.

I tried using switchMap, but not sure  if this needs to be done outside the .expand or is there a better method on observable to do this ?

I have the method for deleteById too.

In the following existing code ,  Can you please help with how this needs to be do

```js
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let temp = [];
    let obj = {};
    let queryIds = [];
    this.restService.observable.post(CREATE, val).expand(response => {
        obj = response.json();
        if (obj && obj.Count > 0) {
            return this.restService.observable.get(`${GET_NEXT}?id=${obj.id}`);
        } else if (obj && obj.Count === 0) {
            //returns an observable of each obj's id for delete request
            //return this.restModuleService.observable.get(`${DELETE}?id=${obj.id}`);
            //instead need to push the id's into an array 
            and make a delete request on teh array of ids
            //queryIds.push(obj.id);
            //return Observable.empty();

        } else {
            return Observable.empty();
        }
    })**.toArray().mergeMap(objects => {
            const objArray = objects.map(obj => obj.json());
            const toDelete = objArray.filter(obj => obj.remainingCount === 0);
            return this.deleteByIds(toDelete);
    })**.map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if (data) {
            temp.push.apply(temp, data.results);
        }
    });
```

);

The deleteById method

```js
   deleteByIds(queryIds, cb) {
    var data = {
        data: {
            ids: []
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < queryIds.length; i++) {
        data.data.ids.push(queryIds[i]);
    }
    let payload = JSON.stringify(data);
    return this.restService.post('deleteBulk', payload)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch((error) => {
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every value that you emit from within your expand operation will trickle through your stream. So you can do your initial request, expand all additionals where needed and after that accumulate all deletions into one operation like so:

```js
doRequestForObject(1)
  .expand(obj => {
    if(obj.count == 0) {
      return Rx.Observable.empty();
    }
    /* keep getting objects */
    return doRequestForObject(1 + obj.id);
  })
  .toArray()
  .mergeMap(objects => {
    /* in here objects is an array so we can use Array.filter() */
    const toDelete = objects.filter(obj => obj.count === 0);
    return deleteObjects(toDelete)
      .concat(Rx.Observable.of(objects.filter(obj => obj.count > 0)));
  })
  .subscribe(console.log, console.log, () => console.log("done"));


function doRequestForObject(i) {
  return Rx.Observable.of({
    id: i,
    count: i % 5
  });
}

function deleteObjects(idArray) {
  console.log('deleting: ' + JSON.stringify(idArray));
  return Rx.Observable.empty();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.11/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks  for the clear explanation this helps. will try it out

Comment: This works, however , i do have a .map on each of the expanded observable that then uses the response .json to subscribe to teh data and act on it. The problem i am seeing with this approach is that , the .map does not get the response as the .toArray().mergeMap consolidates the observables.  I will still need the response for each observable to do what its doing and at the end of it call the bulk delete operation

Comment: I have edited the actual code above to show what i have currently